# Low quality image into a label

Tags: vb.net, image, bitmap, label

I'm trying to pass an image showing to the user a countdown. For this, I'm using a separate thread where I'm checking when the countdown timer should be started, and when so, I draw an image for every 6 seconds passed.

What's annoying is when I pass the drawn image to the UI, the quality of the image is changed and it looks bad to the user.

This is my little script that handles the drawings:

```
Try
   remainingTime = (#12:04:00 AM# - (DateTime.Now - local_DateTimeclick)).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
   remainingTimeInSeconds = Convert.ToDateTime(remainingTime).Minute * 60 + Convert.ToDateTime(remainingTime).Second

   If remainingTimeInSeconds Mod 6 = 0 Then
      g.ResetTransform()
      g.TranslateTransform(52, 52)
      g.RotateTransform(230 - remainingTimeInSeconds / 6 * 9)

      'g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
      'g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
      'g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
      'g.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
      'g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.

      g.DrawImage(Tick, 10, 10)
   End If

Catch
   remainingTime = "Times Up"
End Try
```

In the above section, 
- *local_DateTimeClick* is the variable that is set when the countdown should start
- *Tick* is a Bitmap that represents the image i have to draw for every 6 elipsed seconds
- *g* is a Graphics object from image that i return into the main window.

Also tried with changing the properties of *g*, but there was no positive effect.

Anyone have any idea what can i do to make this properly work without changing the quality of the returned image? Any tip/advice is welcomed.

Comment: Why have you commented out all the magic code to make it look high quality?

Comment: Because it makes no difference. The image's quality is the same either if im using the "magic code" or not.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Drawing2D.SmoothingMode` only applies for 2D vector drawing methods such as `Graphics.DrawEllipse` and `Graphics.DrawLine`.

It doesn't affect drawing bitmaps with `Graphics.DrawImage`.

From the [.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx):

> The smoothing mode specifies whether lines, curves, and the edges of filled areas use smoothing (also called antialiasing).

You have two options at this point:

1. Pre-render every possible orientation of the image, and then just display different `Image` objects at each tick
2. use the [.NET vector drawing methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.aspx) to render your image instead of using a pre-rendered bitmap.

Without knowing the actual image you're transforming, I can't say which would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

from a graphic designer perspective followed at my company, i think your should crop your images to fit in the label:
1. it enhance performance by saving processing power.
2. it look better ?!.
regards

Comment: Well ... I'm not resizing anything, so i think there's no need to make crops. But I'll search some tips for this and will try.